# Whats the difference between intval and floatval?

Tags: php, wordpress

I see no difference when testing this code

```
$stock_threshold = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_out_of_stock_threshold', true );
$new_stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity() - intval($stock_threshold);
var_dump( $new_stock_quantity );
```

**Update :** I don't need decimal places, only whole numbers for stock quantity. I have no errors using either, just wanted to know the difference but i assume the reason i need to use this is because of the  negative stock levels in the database like - 35 where the DB doesn't like a minus sign.

I've been forced to use `intval()` to avoid numeric the error : non-numeric value encountered.

```
$stock_threshold = 2
$new_stock_quantity = 8
```

Comment: What's the value of `$stock_threshold`, and what are you getting back? The difference between [intval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) and [floatval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) are the same difference between int and float -- ints are whole numbers, floats have decimal values.

Comment: Sounds like an XY question. https://3v4l.org/trnJi What do you have for that variable? `intval` and `floatval` have the same error notice handlers. View manually entries and it is noted there.

Comment: Thanks @aynber. Thats all i needed to know.

Comment: If you get the error "_non-numeric value encountered_", it means some queries return an invalid numeric value, and you really want to ensure that you don't get invalid values by forcing a non-numeric value into an integer. Is your DB column holding the stock threshold always an integer?

Comment: Not sure on the DB but i know the return value can be a - minus as its the stock level minus a custom threshold which could equate to a minus, Not sure how to fix this?

Comment: Expand on "DB doesn't like a minus sign". Is your column unsigned? Do you want it to be unsigned?

Answer (score 1):

**intval:** The intval() function returns the integer value of a variable.

**Parameter Values:**

*variable* - Required. Specifies the variable to check
*base*    - Optional. Specifies the base to use for the conversion. Only has an effect if the variable is a string. The default base is 10

-> The integer value of the variable on success, 0 on failure. An empty array will return 0, and a non-empty array will return 1. It takes a variable as an argument and returns its integer value. If the variable contains a string that starts with a numeric value, it will return the integer value of that string. If the variable contains a float, it will return the integer portion of that float. If the variable contains a non-numeric value, it will return 0.

**Examples:**

```
echo intval(35) . "<br>";     // output: 35

echo intval(3.5) . "<br>";    // output: 3

echo intval("35.2") . "<br>";  // output: 35

echo intval(array()) . "<br>";  // output: 0

echo intval(array("red", "green", "blue")) . "<br>";   // output: 1
```

**floatval:** The floatval() function returns the float value of a variable.

**Parameter Values:**

*variable*  - Required. Specifies the variable to check. Must be a scalar type

-> The float value of the variable on success, 0 on failure. An empty array will return 0, and a non-empty array will return 1. It takes a variable as an argument and returns its floating-point value. If the variable contains a string that starts with a numeric value, it will return the floating-point value of that string. If the variable contains an integer, it will convert it to a float. If the variable contains a non-numeric value, it will return 0.

**Examples:**

```
echo floatval("235.567889") . "<br>";    // Output: 235.567889

echo floatval("235.567889Example") . "<br>";   // Output: 235.567889

echo floatval(35.56) . "<br>";  // Output: 35.56

echo floatval("Example123") . "<br>";    // Output: 0
```

Comment: How about for negative values with a minus sign like - 35

Comment: The output will be `-35` for both (intval and floatval)

Comment: That's what i want to avoid. A negative in the Database.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? As you said just wanted to know the difference.

Comment: Question has been updated.

Comment: Are you getting a negative value from the database and want to avoid the minus sign?